# progressview in TableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: swift, uikit, progress-bar

[image]I made a custom cell that has progressView in it.
I set the timer and every second it updates progressbar.
Everything works fine when I use color such as UIcolor.red, UIcolor.green.

The problem occurs when I modify its color or use custom color creaded by hexcode.
The progressBar starts at 0.25 point and until it goes beyond that point, it doesn't update.

enter image description here
This is unexpected behavior.

[image: unexpected behavior. It should not have the same progress until it is full]

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UITableViewController {[![enter image description here][3]][3]
    
    
    var time = 0
    var progressNumber:Float = 0.2
    let dummyArray = ["Pull Up","IOS","Strecthing","Bench Press"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "progreeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTime() {

        progressNumber += 0.1
       
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
       
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        progressNumber += 0.03
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dummyArray.count
    }
    
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! progreeCell
        
        
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = dummyArray[indexPath.row]

        
        cell.progressBar.progress = progressNumber / Float(indexPath.row + 1)
        cell.progressBar.alpha = 0.5
        
        cell.progressBar.progressViewStyle = .bar
        
        let color = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1)

        
        
        
        cell.progressBar.progressTintColor = color
        
        

        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: You need to show us how you've setup your "progreeCell" xib file and class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did not write any code. I just added progress bar with Stroyboard then gave it a constraint [top, bottom, right, left] zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some searching indicates this is a bug in `UIProgressView`...

- **IF** ...

  - the progress view Height is > 20
- ***and***

  - we call `progressBar.progressTintColor = color`

we see the issue.

Since your UI design requires the progress view Height to be greater than 20, you can avoid the problem by using `.tintColor` instead:

```
cell.progressBar.tintColor = color
```

As a side note... many "built-in" UI controls have quirks (and bugs). You may want to swap your `UIProgressView` out for a normal `UIView` and update its width constraint.